# How to retrieve Google Directions GPS data from real device

Tags: android, directions, google-directions-api

I'm trying to make an application based on Google Directions (Maps) API. Basically, I'll develop a mobile app which will tell users where to navigate with their cars and I'll monitor the actual trip (route followed, time, speed etc). Then, I'll need to process the data retrieved in order to display it on a web platform and compute some statistics.

My questions is, which API should I use and how? I've actually searched about this topic but I couldn't find something useful (like a tutorial) regarding this subject, given the fact that I'm new in this domain and I don't know how to begin and what to do.

Thus, I would really appreciate if you can give me some steps that I must follow in order to accomplish this. Also, all types of materials (tutorials, documentations, articles and anything regarding that subject and tips for really beginners) would be very, very helpful for me!

Comment: please tell us what you have researched so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
Refer the following link for directions API documentation.
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

```
You can refer the following link for parsing directions.
```

https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

```
On Location Listener,listen continuosly your current location and store in a list and after the trip is completed,You can use that list that which path that the user as travelled and do your algorithm according to your requirement.
```